# create 64 bit jni under windows

Tags: windows, dll, java-native-interface

while porting tools to different Systems I have encounter a Problem with windows 64 bit.

I have successfully build dlls with linux 32/64 and windows32. I have tried mingw-64 with msys but unfortunately I get only 32 bit dlls. This is a part of my script to obtain the dlls

gcc -o tool_jni.dll -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -     IC:/Java/jdk/include -IC:/Java/jdk/include/win32 $SOURCES

I get NO error messages, just not the desired DLLs

I am open for any solution. I dont have to use the script, I just need the DLLs.

Comment: Is MinGW a requirement? I successfully compile 64-bit DLLs using [Windows 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), when using [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/), just for reference ;)

Comment: @SamuelAudet no requirements at all. I will try it with win sdk

Comment: @SamuelAudet do you remember the key steps you had taken, to compile the DLLs?

Comment: One of the reasons I created [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) was to make all of that automatic, without needing to remember all that. Mind you, I never tested with MinGW-w64, so who knows if it works..

Comment: meanwhile I solved it with mingw-w64... mingw-w64 with msys + the gcc command is missing -m64 ...took just hours to find out :)

Comment: Ah, good to know! I guess you should answer your own question below for completeness.